# What is the best way to buy this food?? Please help, have the basics.

Tags: linear-algebra

```
Prices:2016     |14 Meals| 28meals | 60 meals | 120 meals | 240 meals |

                  $74       $148      $222       $296        $370
```

Throughout 2 years I will be needing to eat exactly 1248 meals. During the weekends (sat and sun.) only 1 meal is consumed a day, and during the week (M-F) 2 meals are consumed a day.

What is the cheapest way to buy all the supplies needed within before 2016 is over?

Begins: Jan 02, 2016 Ends: Jan 02, 2018

Struggling right now with this, but I got the 1248 meals by adding the weekend food and the food for the week.  Re-post, I forgot my work.

```
            2((1)(2)(52)) + 2((2)(5)(52))
                     208  +    1040
                          1248


 240+240+240+240+240=1200
     1200+48=1248
         So I need another 48?
             Would it be better to buy smaller things?
                   Or is there another way of going about this?



                   14  is $5.2 per meal

                   28  is $5.2 per meal

                   60  is $3.7 per meal

                   120 is $2.4 per meal

                   240 is $1.5 per meal
```

Comment: I don't know whether this was meant or not, but the date range you provide has 366*2 days (one extra day for February 29 and one extra day for eating on January 2nd 3 times). You took into consideration only 2*52*7 days which is 728 as opposed to 732 days. Out of those 4 extra days, 2 are weekend days, so you may need 6 extra meals.

Answer (score 0):

Solve: $14x+60y=1248$, $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$

$\Rightarrow 7x+30y=624$

$$ 7x\equiv24\pmod{30},\ 2y\equiv1 \pmod{7}$$
$$ x\equiv 13\cdot24\equiv 12 \pmod{30},\ y\equiv 4\pmod{7} $$
$$\begin{align} 7(12+30k)+30(4+7\ell)&=624 \\
210(k+\ell)+204&=624 \\
k+\ell&=2
\end{align}$$

Since we want to minimize $x$, we let $k=0$, $\ell=2$, so $x=12$, $y=18$.  Now, $12\times 14$ can be simplified to $6\times 28$, while $18\times 60=120+4\times 240$, so your best plan is 6 of the 28-meal package, 1 of the 120 meal package, and 4 of the 240 meal package.

Comment: It’s cheaper to buy $5$ $240$-meal packages and one $60$-meal package, even though you get $12$ extra meals that way.